# How can I add a new audio track with uploaded sounds or music?

Tags: youtube, video, youtube-studio

It seems as if YouTube Studio is still in alpha. There is no obvious way to upload your own sounds or music to use as a track, and you're stuck with their own canned sounds.

There's even a link to an "audio library" which allows you to only to download mp3 files from the library of sound effects, but no apparent way to actually upload them (or your own audio files) to the video editor.

Is it possible to upload your own audio files, or is Google still figuring out video editing basics while we're all waiting impatiently?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no option in Youtube Studio to add your own music track. You can only use the music from the Audio Library.

A workaround would be to download your video form Youtube and with your favourite video editing tool, add the music and then re-upload the video. You will loose all your view count and comments; if you want to retain them, keep the original video as 'unlisted' so that it will be still available with the link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that Youtube studio has such an opportunity. Maybe someone else can answer this question. I know that the [Tunecore](https://emanate.live/distribution) music distributor allows users to send their creative works to the most popular streaming platforms. You can use the emanate service and upload your own music there. Try it, I am personally satisfied with the service.

Answer (score -2):

When it comes to YouTube I would only upload tracks from their own list. Today they say one thing, tomorrow they will change their mind and ban you for copyright infrindement. As for me, I don't use them at all. It is easier for me to use [Mp3Juice](https://mp3juice.link) and download whatever track they have to my iPod. I have bad internet connection at home, so this really helps.